# SocialEngine 4 Calculate days left in membership

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

What I am trying to do is show a small widget on the home page to let a user know when their membership expires.  Here is my current code

```
$subExpire = Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('subscriptions', 'payment');
$db2 = $streamTable->getAdapter();
$stmt2 = $db2->query("select * from engine4_payment_subscriptions where `user_id`='$user_id'");
$arr2 = $stmt2->fetch();

if ($arr2['expiration_date']=="NULL")
{
    $exp = "NEVER";
}
echo $exp;
```

I think the major issue has to do with Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('subscriptions', 'payment');

Ultimately once it comes back with a date I would like to calculate how many days left in the membership from the current date.

Any suggestions?

PS, $user_id is defined and does return a numeric value

One more thing, the actual table name is engine4_payment_subscriptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That´s a strange way of making the query in social engine, try this:

> $table = Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('subscriptions', 'payment');
>
> $select = $table->select()->where('user_id = ?', $user_id);
>
> $arr2 = $table->fetchAll($select);
>
> if ($arr2['expiration_date']=="NULL")
>
> {
>
> $exp = "NEVER";
>
> }
>
> echo $exp;